# Central automorphisms of finite $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Let an automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$  commutes with every inner automorphism of $G$. I want to prove that $x^{-1}\alpha(x)\in Z(G)$, the centre of $G$. But  i am not able to prove this fact. Can someone please help.

Comment: Let $i_g$ be any inner automorphism of $G$. Then $\alpha. i_g=i_g .\alpha$. Thus $ i_g.\alpha(x)=\alpha. i_g(x)$ and hence $g^{-1} \alpha(x) g=(\alpha(G))^{-1}\alpha(x)\alpha(g)$.

Comment: Let $i_g$ be any inner automorphism of $G$. Then $\alpha. i_g=i_g .\alpha$. Thus $ (i_g.\alpha)(x)=(\alpha. i_g)(x)$ and hence $g^{-1} \alpha(x) g=(\alpha(g))^{-1}\alpha(x)\alpha(g)$.

Answer (score 2):

$i_g$ is the inner automorphism which is conjugation by $g$: $i_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$.

(1) For any automorphism $\alpha$, prove that $\alpha i_g \alpha^{-1}$ is equal to  $i_{\alpha(g)}$ (conjugation by $\alpha(g)$).

(2) So if $\alpha$ commutes with every $i_g$ i.e. $\alpha i_g\alpha^{-1}=i_g$ i.e. then by (1), $i_{\alpha(g)}=i_g$ for all $g\in G$.

(3) So $(i_g)^{-1}i_{\alpha(g)}$ is identity, i.e. $i_{g^{-1}\alpha(g)}$ is identity.

(4) For what $x\in G$, the inner automorphism $i_x$ is identity?